# How to resolve Soap header action not understood?

Tags: c#, mobile, soap

I'm developing on VS2008 for Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional I get this error message "Soap header action not understood"

I see a lot of post on the subject but none for Windows Mobile.

Any help would be appreciated.

Link to the URL with the XML data

https://silulumanzi.4most.co.za:4343/SIZA.svc?wsdl

How Rene and what [silulumanzi.4most.co.za:4343/SIZA.svc](https://silulumanzi.4most.co.za:4343/SIZA.svc) suggested ?

```
public void GetOpenPO()
    {
        //Get open purchase order numbers and populate combo box

        try
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
            //binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
            EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://silulumanzi.4most.co.za:4343/SIZA.svc?wsdl"));

            SizaWS.SIZA client = new SizaWS.SIZA();

            string[] Response = client.GetOpenPO();

            //Popuplate combo box with data received from web service
            comboBox2.Items.Add("");
            for (int i = 0; i < Response.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Response[i])))
                {
                    comboBox2.Items.Add(Response[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
```

No service reference

[image]

Config File I added

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ISIZA" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
        transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
        allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
          enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
            establishSecurityContext="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://silulumanzi.4most.co.za:4343/SIZA.svc"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ISIZA"
      contract="ISIZA" name="WSHttpBinding_ISIZA" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Error List

[image]

The version System.ServiceModel

[image]

Comment: A SOAP is an XML response that normally has the tags Envelope, Body,Header (optional) and then a user define tag.  You also need c# classes for each of the XML tags.  The Action maps the XML  to the classes.  The looks like you have a discrepancy between the response and your classes.

Comment: I did create my classes for the XML tags

Comment: I added a web reference to get the XML tags

Comment: Is that SIZA.svc the service you're calling or are you hosting that service? Can you share your bindings as configured in the app.config/web.config.

Comment: @rene 
vs2008 did not create an app.config/web.config file for me. How do I get one then? I'm calling that service

Comment: Open your visual studio 2008 command prompt, run `svcutil https://silulumanzi.4most.co.za:4343/SIZA.svc?wsdl /out:\temp\siza.cs /config:\temp\siza.config` that will give you an wcf client in the .cs file and in the .config file stuff that needs to go in the config of your app. Create the wcfclient in your code, and call the method you need on it.

Comment: Thanks for the script. I did run it and it did create the two files you mentioned. But the rest I did not fully understand. Sorry I'm a bit new to this.

Comment: add the cs file to your project, then do `SIZA_Scanner.SIZAClient client = new SIZA_Scanner.SIZAClient(); string[] results = client.GetOpenSTR();`  and then do something useful with what is returned in `results`. Merge the .config file in your existing config file. also see https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/DavidAiken/VS2008-Training-Kit-Web-Programming-with-WCF for background.

Comment: I did what you suggested @rene but still gives me the same error when I run it

Comment: See following : https://silulumanzi.4most.co.za:4343/SIZA.svc

Comment: @jdweng see code edit

Comment: Can this maybe be the problem is that I added a web reference and not a service reference. The reason I used web reference is because there was no option to add a service reference. See screen shot added

Comment: The soap endpoint is using soap12 and therefor needs the [wshttpbinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) as is shown on the .config file you generated. The binding takes care of adding the correct headers/actions in both the HTTP as the SOAP header.

Comment: @rene I added the config file to the post

Comment: Getting same error when adding the config file

Comment: I got code to run.  Code returns four numbers : 1905, 1906, 1907, 1908.  The client is in the cs file generated by the svcutil.exe.  You have to add to your application.  It has a different namespace so client should be referenced as : SIZA_Scanner.SIZAClient client = new SIZA_Scanner.SIZAClient();

Comment: I've added the cs file that was generated and I get a 112 errors of namespace names that does not exist. I've added all the references I can. 

I'm using vs2008 for Smartdevice development 

See screen shot added

Comment: I did add the references that gives the error. But it does not help.

Comment: Did you really add a reference to the system.servicemodel.dll ? Because all the versions I have of that assembly do have an ClientBase for example so it would be very weird if you have a version that doesn't. It is more likely you didn't add the reference to the right project or picked a wrong version.

Comment: @rene See screenshot of reference. Sorry if I seem clueless I have Clarion and Kotlin background but no C# and SOAP experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a fully working VS2008 but I've reproduced your problem and here are the steps to resolve the problem you face for one specific call, in this case GetOpenPO. It is a hack. I can't find a better solution for now.

First of all, get rid of the Web Refence and the Service Reference and any files you added based on my comments.

Add the textfile 'GenClient.xml' to your project and enter the following options (based on documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/7h3ystb6(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN))

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<wsdlParameters xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webReference/">
  <webReferenceOptions>
    <verbose>false</verbose>
    <codeGenerationOptions>properties oldAsync</codeGenerationOptions>
    <style>client</style>
  </webReferenceOptions>
</wsdlParameters>
```

After saving this achieves that the service client gets generate with .Net 1.1 style Begin/EndInvoke methods, omitting any use of System.Threading.

Open the Visual Studio 2008 Command prompt. Change Directory to your project directory. Run the following command to generate a SIZA.cs class that will act as your soap client (it takes the earlier created and saved genclient.xml as parameters file):

**This will overwrite your current SIZA.cs. Re-apply changes afterwards**

```sh
wsdl /out:SIZA.cs /protocol:soap12 /parameters:genclient.xml https://silulumanzi.4most.co.za:4343/SIZA.svc?wsdl
```

You will now have a SIZA.cs file in your project folder.

Open your project in Visual Studio 2008.
In the solution explorer, right-click your project, Add Existing Item and in the filedialog and find the SIZA.cs in your project root folder.

In the solution Explorer, right click on References, choose "Add Reference", wait for the dialog to load and then from the .Net tab find and select assembly System.Web.Services, click OK.

Your solution should compile now without errors.

This is where the hack starts :/

In the SIZA.cs file find the following method:

```
public string[] GetOpenPO() {
```

Right before that method add this Attribute:

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader("Soap12HdrGetOpenPO", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
```

Your end result should look like this:

```
/// <remarks/>    
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/ISIZA/GetOpenPO", RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]

[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader("Soap12HdrGetOpenPO", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]

public string[] GetOpenPO() {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("GetOpenPO", new object[0]);
    return ((string[])(results[0]));
}
```

Create a new Class file and name it: SIZA.Partial.cs

Add the following code in that new file, replacing everything that is in it:

```
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml;

public partial class SIZA
{

    private SoapUnknownHeader CreateSoapAcionHeader(string hdr, string value)
    {
        var xd = new XmlDocument();
        var sh = new SoapUnknownHeader();
        sh.MustUnderstand = true;
        sh.Element = xd.CreateElement(hdr, "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
        sh.Element.InnerText = value;
        return sh;
    }

    // this method gets called due to the added SoapHeader attribute
    public SoapUnknownHeader[] Soap12HdrGetOpenPO
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
                {
                    CreateSoapAcionHeader("Action", "http://tempuri.org/ISIZA/GetOpenPO"), 
                    CreateSoapAcionHeader("To", this.Url), 
                };
        }
        set { /* empty */}
    }
}
```

This will basically add the missing SOAP12 Action and To header to the soap envelope for the GetOpenPO call. And that makes the WCF service you're calling happy as well.

Here is a fiddler screenshot of what gets exchanged on the wire:

[image]

The downside of this solution is that you need to do this manually for every public method in the SIZA client you want to use. Maybe someone else comes by and remembers how one of the extension points in the [SoapHttpClientProtocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol?view=netframework-3.5) should be leveraged.

Comment: Hi Rene, thanks for the answer I added the code you gave. But still get "The type or namespace name 'SendOrPostCallback' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Threading' (are you missing an assembly reference)

System.Threading is not here to add to my project

Comment: @Fourie I've added a parameters file to be used that should help not using System.Threading. The answer and procedure slightly changed so it now regenerates the SIZA.cs in place.

Comment: Hi Rene, this did solve my problem. But the company decided to upgrade their device to a Win10 mobile device. So going to code in Xamarin in a newer version of Visual Studio.